# Get Mouse Position

Tags: java, mouse

I would like to simulate a natural mouse movement in Java (going from here to there pixel by pixel). To do that I need to know the starting coordinates.

I've found the method event.getX() and event.getY() but I need an event...

How can I know the positions without doing anything (or something not visible)?

Thank you

Answer (score 245, accepted):

[MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html#getLocation%28%29) might be helpful. It returns a [Point](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) object corresponding to current mouse position.

Comment: `getPointerInfo().getLocation()` returns the position relative to the screen. If you want the position relative to your component (like given by MouseListeners) you can subtract `yourComponent.getLocationOnScreen()` from it.

Comment: +1 `Container.getMousePosition()` can some times return `null` if the mouse is moving too fast, using this avoids the issue.

Comment: In addition to what @ThomasAhle said, you can avoid implementing it yourself, by using an already implemented convinience method: `SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(), component)`

Comment: Note `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo()` can return null when there is no mouse or in some multimon setups.

Comment: Note that `SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(..)` converts the first argument in-place and doesn't return anything, so it needs to be written a bit differently relative to @AndreiVajnaII comment so that we can get hold of the `Point` object.

Comment: Is there an event to which one could register a listener to get notified the mouse moved?

Answer (score 46):

```
PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point b = a.getLocation();
int x = (int) b.getX();
int y = (int) b.getY();
System.out.print(y + "jjjjjjjjj");
System.out.print(x);
Robot r = new Robot();
r.mouseMove(x, y - 50);
```

Answer (score 12):

In SWT you need not be in a listener to get at the mouse location. The Display object has the method `getCursorLocation()`.

In vanilla SWT/JFace, call `Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation()`.

In an RCP application, call `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getCursorLocation()`.

For SWT applications, it is preferable to use `getCursorLocation()` over the `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo()` that others have mentioned, as the latter is implemented in the AWT toolkit that SWT was designed to replace.

Answer (score 8):

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    while(true){
      //Thread.sleep(100);
      System.out.println("(" + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + 
              ", " + 
              MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y + ")");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Cords {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        //get cords of mouse code, outputs to console every 1/2 second
        //make sure to import and include the "throws in the main method"

        while(true == true)
        {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1/2);
        double mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
        double mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
        System.out.println("X:" + mouseX);
        System.out.println("Y:" + mouseY);
        //make sure to import 
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try looking at the java.awt.Robot class. It allows you to move the mouse programatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Swing as your UI layer, you can use a [Mouse-Motion Listener](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) for this.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing something like this to get mouse coordinates using Robot, I use these coordinates further in few of the games I am developing:

```
public class ForMouseOnly {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
        int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
        while (true) {

            if (x != MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x || y != MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y) {
                System.out.println("(" + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + ", "
                        + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y + ")");
                x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
                y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I was supposed to open a dialog box in the mouse position based on a GUI operation done with the mouse. The following code worked for me:

```
    public Object open() {
    //create the contents of the dialog
    createContents();
    //setting the shell location based on the curent position
    //of the mouse
    PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point pt = a.getLocation();
    shellEO.setLocation (pt.x, pt.y);

    //once the contents are created and location is set-
    //open the dialog
    shellEO.open();
    shellEO.layout();
    Display display = getParent().getDisplay();
    while (!shellEO.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using SWT, you might want to look at adding a MouseMoveListener as explained [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/UsingMouseMoveListener.htm).

Comment: but the Listener is executed only if I do something (move, click) with my mouse, right ? The first thing I need before moving it is to know the starting position