# How can I speed up the mouse pointer movement with the Robot class?

Tags: java, mouse, awt, mouse-cursor, awtrobot

I know that I can move the mouse pointer with the `java.awt.Robot()` class to a specific screen location, but I need the movement to go a bit faster without losing the smoothness.

I tried setting the `AutoDelay` option to 1, but that is not fast enough when used on a display resolution like 1680x1050. Setting it to 0 would do the job instantly.

Is there any way I could speed up the movement with the `Robot` class or any other lib?

Comment: Perhaps use a timer (or timer-loop waiting for the queue to empty), time delta, current and target mouse locations and move the mouse multiple times: it may have to jump by multiple pixels. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439022/get-mouse-position for hints.

Comment: Or use C/C++ or something similar.

Comment: I tried with AutoDelay 1 and moving it by two pixels at a time (eg. xLocation += 2), I think this speed/smoothness will be fine. Thank you.