# How to get mouse position without Listener but inside of a component, or Change global Variables inside of MouseListeners

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouse, listener

I have a problem changing variables values in the mouseMoved method, i try to use the MouseMotionListener but doesn't work, i try all i can use. The form it works a little bit more is `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();` and `a.getLocation();`, but give me the position of the mouse outside of my frame, and i need a way to have the cursor position inside of my frame.
in this code you can see i try the mouseMoved way, but don't change the Global variable x2 and i want that, or change booleans, but Doesn't work.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    //System.out.println("x" + x);
    //System.out.println("y" + y);
    this.x2 = e.getX();
    y2 = e.getY();
    //MouseSelect(x2, y2);
    /*if(x >= 150 && x <= 650){
        if(y >= 150 && y <= 249){
            System.out.println("adentro");
        }
    }*/
}
```

And now this is the method i use to modificate booleans

```
public void MouseSelect(double d, double e){
    if(d >= 150 && d <= 650){
        if(e >= 150 && e <= 249){
            System.out.println("Adentro");
            Mjugarsel = true;
            Macercasel = false;
            Msalirsel = false;
            currentChoice = 1;
        }else{
            Mjugarsel = false;
            Macercasel = false;
            Msalirsel = false;
        }
    }else{
        Mjugarsel = false;
        Macercasel = false;
        Msalirsel = false;
    }
    if(d >= 150 && d <= 650){
        if(e >= 301 && e <= 398){
            Mjugarsel = false;
            Macercasel = true;
            Msalirsel = false;
            currentChoice = 2;
        }else{
            Mjugarsel = false;
            Macercasel = false;
            Msalirsel = false;
        }
    }else{
        Mjugarsel = false;
        Macercasel = false;
        Msalirsel = false;
    }
    if(d >= 150 && d <= 650){
        if(e >= 451 && e <= 547){
            Mjugarsel = false;
            Macercasel = false;
            Msalirsel = true;
            currentChoice = 3;
        }else{
            Mjugarsel = false;
            Macercasel = false;
            Msalirsel = false;
        }
    }else{
        Mjugarsel = false;
        Macercasel = false;
        Msalirsel = false;
    }
}
```

I don't forget this thing `addMouseListener(this)` and `addMouseMotionListener(new MenuState(gsm)`

The only thing i want is change booleans, if the cursor is in the X and Y coordinates i want, make Mjugarsel = true; something like that. but when i try it, the variable doesn't change.

Comment: The MouseInfo provides information in screen relative coordinates

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Mouse Position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439022/get-mouse-position)