# How to get mouse postion without a window

Tags: java, mouse

I want to get the mouse postion but I don't want anyone to see the program. The problem is i don't know to get mouse postion without a JFrame I mean evryone can see that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Mouse Position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439022/get-mouse-position)