# How to draw string that displays Mouse X and Mouse Y?

Tags: java, string, awt, drawstring

```
     String mouse = new String(getMouseX(), getMouseY());

    public void paintFrame(Graphics g) {

        g.drawString("mouse", 100,100);
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to display the X and Y coordinates of the mouse on the screen when the program is executed. I know this is wrong, but could someone point me in the right direction? I'm fairly new to Java and am still getting used to writing code.

Comment: What GUI framework are you working in?

Comment: you mean you want to draw the value of variable `mouse`, right? like: `g.drawString(mouse, 100,100);`
notice: without quote

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Mouse Position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439022/get-mouse-position)

Comment: @EvanKnowles no idea, how would I check?

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 I believe so. I want the screen to display X=*mouse x position here* and Y=*mouse x position here*

Comment: @Max I don't think that is a duplicate, I want something visible on my screen that updates as I move the mouse.

Comment: have you tried that? removing the quote..? does it work..?
it "might" be your problem.. because I don't know your full code..

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 Tried it, returned with 'no suitable constructor found for String(int,int)' as well as argument mismatch errors.

Comment: what is that? can you show me your code..?
if you are trying this one: `g.drawString(mouse, 100,100);`, then the error like the one you mentioned is not possible..

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 the code is a program that my Intro to Java professor had written, there's basically a section that he is having us input small snippets of code into, then recompiling the program and checking results. I've managed to get it to work though, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Swing, you can get the current relative position of your mouse in the window as a Point by

```
Point cursorPosition = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
```

afterwards you can print out the X and Y position by

```
System.out.print("X: " + cursorPosition.x + " Y: " + cursorPosition.y);
```

or as you mentioned in your question you might want to do

```
String position = "X: " + cursorPosition.x + " Y: " + cursorPosition.y)";
g.drawString(position, 100, 100);
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! `public void paintFrame(Graphics g) {

 String position = new String("X: " + getMouseX() + " Y: " + getMouseY());
 g.drawString(position, 100, 100);
 
 }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw the string 'mouse' at the current position of the mouse, try this:

```
public void paintFrame(Graphics g) {
    Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    g.drawString("mouse", p.x, p.y);
}
```

Or if you want to draw a string containing the position of the mouse use:

```
public void paintFrame(Graphics g) {
    Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    String mousePos = p.x +";"+ p.y;
    g.drawString(mousePos, 100, 100);
}
```

I'm not sure of what you exactly want, but the important aspect is that you can get mouse position by calling:

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
```

This will return you a Point object, therefore you can refer to the x and y fields of this object: they are the coordinates of the current mouse position.

I hope this will help you.