# how to display a bar when mouse cursor is moved to a corner?

Tags: java, swing

In windows 8 when a user moves his mouse cursor to the right a control bar with some buttons is shown. So, can this be done in a java application? I want that when a user moves his mouse cursor to left a similar control bar pops-up with some buttons. Is something like that possible? 
Note: My java application fits the width and height of the screen(fullscreen application).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Mouse Position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439022/get-mouse-position)

Comment: Check the current position of the mouse with a `MouseMotionListener`. If the cursor is inside the area you want, you can set a new pane (Glasspane, to make it easier) visible. On this glasspane you should add the buttons, or whatever.

Comment: @dotvav alright so MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()  helped just half way the code but what about the bar that i wanted to display? should i be a jpanel or what? and what about the transition effect of the bar( the bar should show that it is moving out of the left corner)?

Comment: MouseMotionListener sends billions of events (every single pixel), when you use your programm. Try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a `MouseMotionListener` on the `contentPane` of the frame you are using. And within the `MouseMotionListener` get the mouse position and compare with the value of the corner pixel.

You can do something like

```
getContentPane().addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getX() == 0) //for left corner
            charmsPanel.setVisible(true);   
    }

});
```

Comment: okay but the bar which i wanna setvisible should be what? a jpanel?

Comment: yeah a JPanel would be a good option so that you can internally organize the components and the view of the JPanel

Comment: Animation can only be achieved by writing it manually. we do not have default Java API for that I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example based on @VamshiAlladi 's answer:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    public Example() {

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
        int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();

        JPanel glass = (JPanel) getGlassPane();
        glass.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel bar = new JPanel();
        bar.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            bar.add(new JButton("Button " + i));
        }

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                Point b = a.getLocation();
                int x = (int) b.getX();
                int y = (int) b.getY();
                if (x > Example.this.getWidth() - 10) {
                    glass.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    glass.setVisible(false);
                }
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });

        setSize(width, height);
        glass.add(bar, BorderLayout.EAST);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

Why should you use `GlassPane` and not just a new `JPanel`? - If you have components on your `ContentPane` in the area where the bar will be shown, a (for example) glasspane "overlays" the contentpane. With a JPanel you would have to replace the components (which can cause problems).