# Can I somehow get a position of windows on screen?

Tags: java, window

Is there any method in Java that would return list of positions and dimensions of windows on desktop?

Comment: Yes, I think you could use [jna](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html) to achieve this. Look for questions related to finding Windows location using jna.

Answer (score -1):

Refer This You'll get solution.

[Get Mouse Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439022/get-mouse-position)

Comment: This does not answer the question how to get the position of windows of other processes.