# Getting the DX/DY of a mouse in Java

Tags: java, 2d-games

I'm using Java to create a simple game in `2D`.

However, I would like to get the DX of the mouse so that i can move a certain object to a different place with my mouse in my game.

When i was learning a bit of `LWJGL`, there was a method called

```
Mouse.getDX()/~.getDY()
```

It returns the movement on the `x/y axis` since last time `getDY()` was called.

But I'm not sure how to get such value without using any other libraries like `LWJGL`. I only know **how to get the Mouse Position using the MouseListener interface**. Or is there anything I've done wrong? Thanks if you can answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this StackOverflow: [Get Mouse Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439022/get-mouse-position)

It gives information on how to get the mouse position and gives links to the java API for more details.

Or, use this tutorial to write your own listener, storing the last known position to obtain the delta: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html

Comment: Thanks, but i still don't really know how to get the last known mouse position... ill try reading the page you gave me another time.

Comment: Okay, Now i think i found how i would solve my problem. Thanks! :)